# Is current in a p type semiconductor instantiated by valence electrons?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, semiconductor-physics

We know that free electrons constitute current.Valence electrons does not.Then why in a ptype semiconductor when the majority carriers are holes then valence electrons move and occupy the holes and thus constitute current?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, but you really should embrace the concept of holes and use them. Otherwise most of the concepts in semiconductor physics will remain a deep mystery.

Comment: I do not believe your statement that free electrons constitute current is correct unless I misunderstand it. Any net flux of charge would constitute a current.

Comment: @JanBos Completely agree with you.But still the question remains.Hole current is due to electons occupying the vacant position.These electrons are valence electrons.Valence electrons should not constitute current.

Comment: @JonCuster Hole current is due to electons occupying the vacant position.These electrons are valence electrons.Valence electrons should not constitute current.Posted this question just for enquiry.:) Have known about hole concepts.

Comment: Why do you think that valence electrons cannot carry a current?

Comment: @freecharly Because valence electrons are not "free" like free electrons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free electrons (like, charges in space) certainly can carry current.   So can
the electrons in a metal (at least some of them), because of the
nature of metallic bonding.  Semiconductors are different.

It is common to call the conduction in the valence band 'hole conduction' because the limits on that conduction is the number of holes, not the
(basically infinite) number of available electrons.  But, it really IS valence
electron current, going by the name 'hole current'.   It has to be
given that name, because there are also (some) electrons in the conduction 
band, which move according to different rules, that take the practical
distinctive name, 'electron current'.

Here's the background:

Semiconductor solids have a bunch of low-energy allowed, mainly occupied electron
states (orbitals), with an energy gap between the highest filled 
states (the 'valence band') and the lowest empty states (the 'conduction band').

In a semiconductor at non-zero temperature a few of the valence band electrons
will be missing (and the valence band will have voids, called 'holes').
The loose electrons are unlikely to be found anywhere except the 
lowest-energy available orbitals, the 'conduction band'.

Holes ARE somewhat free to move, because the occupant electrons can make a
transition to an empty 'hole', they aren't in a logjam situation with no
freedom.   Electrons in the conduction band are also free to move, because
there is no energy penalty if they change from one of the (several) 
atomic orbitals in that band to another orbital in the same band.

Answer (score 2):

In the bond picture of a semiconductor like silicon (see, e.g., S.M. Sze, Physics and Technology of Semiconductor Devices), the electron pairs of the four covalent bonds of the Si atoms in the lattice are shared between the neighboring atoms. If an electron is freed from a covalent bond, the missing electron of the covalent bond can propagate from one covalent bond to the next which corresponds to the transport in opposite direction of a positive charge ("hole") in the crystal. When a silicon atom with four valence electrons in the lattice is replaced by an acceptor atom with only three valence electrons, the missing electron (hole) in the four covalent bonds can propagate from one covalent bond to the next through the crystal which  corresponds to a conduction current due to a positive charge. Thus, in this picture, the current in a p-type semiconductor is carried by the movement of valence electrons opposite to the holes missing in covalent bonds.